# Maximal interval Cauchy problem

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

**I need a check on the following problem**

\begin{cases}
y' = \arctan(y) - \frac{1}{x}\\
y(1)=b>0
\end{cases}

- Determine the maximal interval of existence of the solution
- Draw a qualitative graph of the solutions

---

**My attempt:**

- First of all, in an open neigbourhood of the initial data $(1,b)$ (with $b>0$), I have that $$f_y = \frac{1}{1+y^2}$$ is a continuous function, hence we have local existence and uniqueness.
  Now, I look at the stationary solution, which is $$y=\tan\bigl({\frac{1}{x}}\bigr)$$
  and I note that $$y'(1)=0 \text{ if } b=\tan(1)$$  $$y'(1)<0 \text{ if } b<\tan(1)$$ $$y'(1)>0 \text{ if } b>\tan(1)$$

Not only: $$y'(x)> (<) 0 \text{ iff } y >(<) \tan\bigl({\frac{1}{x}}\bigr)$$

Therefore, if $y(1)=b> \tan(1)$, the solution will go to infinity since it increase monotonically, while if $y(1)=b < \frac{\pi}{4}$, then the solution will decrease monotonically towards $-\infty$.

So I would say that the maximal interval is $[1,+\infty)$,

Comment: A couple of questions - how did you find that stationary solution? Also, you did not consider the case $x<1$ - as you wrote, the solution is defined in the neighborhood of $(1,b)$, hence the maximal interval can not stop at $1$.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy I solved for $\arctan(y) = \frac{1}{t}$. You're right about the maximal interval...

Comment: As to local existence and uniqueness, your approach is correct. Note however that $f_y$ does not depend on $x$. Your "stationary" solution is not stationary since it depends on $x$. What is the largest interval on which the solution could possibly exist?

Comment: Your "stationary" solution is not stationary - it depends on $x$! Edit: ah, @HansEngler beat me to this remark.

Comment: @HansEngler you're right, it's not "stationary". In any case, I don't know how to get rid of $x$, since it's like a paramter of the equation

Comment: Thanks to the remark by @HansEngler, I note that I can apply local existence and uniqueness from $[0,+\infty)$. Indeed, the $f_y$ does not have $\frac{1}{x}$, and hence it does not have problem of existence. Of course, if $x=0$, $f(t,x)$ is no more continuous. So I would finally say that the maximal interval is $(0,\infty)$

Comment: Is it okay now for the maximal interval part? If so, what about the qualitative graphs? Is my solution okay? @TZakrevskiy

Comment: You still have to show that the solution actually exists for all $x > 1$ and for all $0 < x < 1$. Use the fact that $|\arctan y| \le \frac{\pi}{2}$ for all $y$. Therefore $- \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{1}{x} \le y' \le  \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{1}{x}$ for all $x$ for which the solution exists. What can you do with that?

Comment: Thanks Hans.


It shows that $|f(t,y)|$ for $x>1$ can be bounded with $\frac{\pi}{2}  + 1$ , so this proves global existence for $x>1$, right? 


But I don't know what to do for $|x|<1$. There the $\frac{1}{x}$ could explode... @HansEngler

Comment: Of course it will explode, at $x = 0$. Otherwise you can use a similar argument.

Comment: @HansEngler I've tried to think about your last comment (for the case $x \in (0,1)$), but all I have in mind is $|f(t,y)| \leq \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{1}{x}$ and as you wrote this bound becomes no more significant as $x \rightarrow 0^{+}$. What similar argument should I use?

Comment: This shows that on any interval $[\varepsilon,1]$ there is a bound $|f| \le K$, so the solution exists on this interval. Therefore it exists for $x > 0$.